# If $u \geq 0$ is harmonic in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and connected, then either $u \equiv 0$ or $u > 0$ in every $\Omega$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, laplacian

I need to prove:

If $u \geq 0$ is harmonic in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and connected, then either $u \equiv 0$ or $u > 0$ in every $\Omega$.

I sought to use Harnack's principle or inequality. Help me, I need more details...

Comment: Since $u$ is harmonic it can't attain an interior minimum unless it is constant.

Comment: I still don't understand. What guarantees this function to have a minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x\in\Omega$, $u(x)$ is the average value of $u$ on any ball $B$ centered at $x$.  Were we to have $u(x) = 0$ for some $x\in \Omega$, then $u$ would be 0 on any ball $B$ centered at $x$ with $B\subseteq \Omega$.  Now use the fact that $\Omega$ is connected.